# Android Webserive response time

Tags: php, web-services

i have created web-service in CorePHP with pgsql database.
first i have created all category listing webservice with the query like

```
"select * from category_mst where active='y'"
```

, this will return json object with total 10 records. when i directly run this web-service from Browser this will complete its execution in 5 second but when i call it form Android application it takes 1.5minute and its too much.
can you suggest me how can i improve the response time for the application ?
thanks in advance

Comment: What are you using in your Android app to make a network call?

Comment: in android i have use simple json parser code. not any network call

Comment: What do you mean you don't have a network call? How are you consuming your API endpoint?